# Receiving the error Class is referenced as a converter but it does not have any converter methods. - androidx.databinding.adapters.Converters

Tags: android, android-room

However, I do have a convertor so i'm not sure why it is causing an issue.

Some code:

```
@Entity(tableName = "category_query_table")
@TypeConverters(Converters.class)
public class CategorySearchResult {
    @NonNull
    @PrimaryKey
    public final String entityId;
    public final List<String> categoryEntityIds;

    public CategorySearchResult(@NonNull String entityId, List<String> categoryEntityIds) {
        this.entityId = entityId;
        this.categoryEntityIds = categoryEntityIds;
    }
}
```

Converter:

```
public class CrosscareConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static List<String> fromString(String value) {
        Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(value, listType);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static String fromArrayList(List<String> list) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        return json;
    }
```

It clearly isn't picking up on using that converter too as it says its never used but this is for both converting to and from a String to list String?

Comment: The refactoring didn't work as intended it seems, it still had the original Converters.class on it

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `@TypeConverters(Converters.class)` that you're putting above the `CategorySearchResult` class, you need to put the name of the class that you created for that matter, in your case: `@TypeConverters(CrosscareConverters.class)`

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the name of `ENUM` class for your variable name.
My problem was wrong naming for variable, I had selected the variable name exactly equal to the `Enum` Class name :
my entity :

```
@Entity(tableName="MediaTable")
class MediaTable (

...

    @SerializedName("MediaType")
    @Expose
    @ColumnInfo(name = "MediaType")
    var MediaType: MediaType,
...
}
```

enum class :

```
enum class MediaType (val value :String){
    NONE("NONE"),
    GImage("GImage"),
    GVideo("GVideo"),
...
}
```

to solve problem i changed the variable name from `MediaType` to `mediaType` :

```
@SerializedName("mediaType")
@Expose
@ColumnInfo(name = "mediaType")
var mediaType: MediaType,
```